# Is there some sort of function that can give me a time frame for the data frame?

Tags: r

So i am trying to group by country and then give a time frame for the events, but I can't figure out how to get the years into a range instead of a list. (1945,1946,1948..) and i want (1945-1950). Any suggestions

```
wars_country_year_SA <- southamerica %>% group_by(country,year) %>% filter(war==1 )%>% summarize(Year = year)
wars_country_year_SA<- wars_country_year_SA[,-2]
wars_country_year_SA <- wars_country_year_SA [order(wars_country_year_SA $Year),]
head(wars_country_year_SA)


Country         Year
PARAGUAY    1947            
COLOMBIA    1948            
COSTARICA   1948            
COLOMBIA    1949            
COLOMBIA    1950            
COLOMBIA    1951
```

Comment: Try with `southamerica %>% group_by(country,year = factor(year, levels = sort(unique(year)))) %>% filter(war==1 )%>% summarize(Year = year)`  If some 'year' is missing and you wanted to have those as well, then use `complete` (not clear without a repreoducible example)

Comment: Are you using `range(Year)` to get the min/max? That'll give you the range as a vector of length 2. (Add `na.rm=TRUE` if you have any `NA`s in the data.) If you need a literal string, then `paste(range(Year), collapse="-")`, though that precludes referencing it by number later.